# Difficulty in sorting selected features

Tags: arcpy, parameters, sorting

My script is terribly underdeveloped, I am trying to select cities within a country and then order these cities by their "POP_RANK" = population rank. I am not sure whether to use a searchcursor or just select the features and then use a sort function.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping
#set workspace
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
#set the dataframe
fc = ("N:\Lab13\cities.shp")
cities = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Cities")[0]
cities.showLabels = True
def countryname():
    country = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    country_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "country_lyr")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(cities, "NEW_SELECTION", "CNTRY_NAME = '{}' ".format(country))
    arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0].zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.Delete_management("country_lyr")
try:
    in_dataset = "CNTRY_NAME"
    out_dataset = "country_sort"
    sort_fields = [["POP_RANK", "ASCENDING"]]
    arcpy.Sort_management(in_dataset, out_dataset, sort_fields)
    arcpy.AddMessage("IT WORKED")
```

Comment: You don't say where the output needs to appear.  If it is in a new feature class that appears as a new layer in the map and shows the order through a table view then the Sort tool works best.  If it is in a MessageBox then the search cursor works best.  Other outputs are also possible.  So what is the goal for interacting with the user?

Comment: The end goal is the user puts a country in the getparameter within an arcmap tool, then it is supposed to zoom to the country, and gives the user the Median population rank for that country. Some how I have to sort the POP_RANK then calculate the median.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the median of the POP_RANK you should use a searchCursor and use list comprehension.  The list can then be fed to method that determines the median.  [I got the method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101524/finding-median-of-list-in-python)

Edit:  You have created confusion by creating two versions of the cities layer in your code.  I have removed the country_layer and instead only use the cities layer, since that is the layer you are actually selecting features from.  By eliminating the useless country_layer the code will now produce the expected median.

```
import arcpy

def median(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    if len(lst) < 1:
            return None
    if len(lst) %2 == 1:
            return lst[((len(lst)+1)/2)-1]
    else:
            return float(sum(lst[(len(lst)/2)-1:(len(lst)/2)+1]))/2.0

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
#set the dataframe
cities = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Cities")[0]
cities.showLabels = True
country = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(cities, "NEW_SELECTION", "CNTRY_NAME = '{}' ".format(country))
arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0].zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
field = "POP_RANK"
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(cities, field)]
mid = median(values)
# do something with mid like print it, message box, etc.
```

Comment: I ran the script and it works, but every outcome I get for the countries is 5. This is not correct because I hand calculated some of them. Can you think of any reason it would do this? Is it calculating the mean for the selected country?

Comment: I fixed the code.  I had based my code on the code you had designed and you had set up 2 city layers, but only selected features in one of them.  I had used the wrong layer.  I have eliminated the useless layer from the code so that now there is only one layer.  The code will work correctly now.